# How do I get my WNA3100 (N-300 netgear wirless adapter) To work on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, netgear

I'm thinking about trying out Ubuntu, however before doing so I want to make sure that I have a way of actually getting the internet up and running so I can properly set myself into Ubuntu through help forums etc, help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just download ubuntu install to usb or burn to cd/ reboot computer / press f12 / then boot from cd or usb / and run live-cd then see if you can connect to wifi. Some harware requires
proprietary drivers.

You can find them under additional drivers for dash home.